# PHP variable value changes

Tags: php

This problem is simpler to explain with the code. Note that functions are located in a different file and are being included on the page.

```
$announcements = $dbc->query($q)->results(); //Returns array of objects
$announcements = prepareMessage($announcements); //Adds html tags to values
$latest = $announcements[0]; //Assign first index to variable
$announcements = truncate($announcements); //Truncate announcement text

function prepareMessage($message) {
    foreach($message as $values => $key) {
        $key->title = '<h2>'.$key->title.'</h2>';
        $key->name = '<p>'.$key->name.'</p>';
        $key->date = '<small>'.humanDate($key->date).'</small>';
    }

    return $message;
}

function truncate($message) {
    foreach($message as $values => $key) {
        $key->announcement = substr($key->announcement, 0, 50) . '...</p>';
    }

    return $message;
}
```

The value of the $latest variable changes after I run this line of code

```
$announcements = truncate($announcements);
```

$latest value before that line is ran

```
[announcement] =>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

$latest value after that line is ran

```
[announcement] =>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisc...
```

So my question is, why is the value of $latest changing?

Comment: Nothing in this code seems to be messing with $latest... perhaps something in the code that outputs $latest to the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$latest` is a reference to `$announcements[0]`, not the actual value of `$announcements[0]`. Instead, use a `clone`. In PHP5, [object assignments are always by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

```
$latest = clone $announcements[0]; //Clone first object in array
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that it was only a reference. I will take note of that for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will help you understand why $latest is changing:

As stated in your code $announcements is an array of objects, simplified it's like this:

```
$test = array(new StdClass(array('a'=>1)));
$latest = $test[0];
$test[0]->a = 3;
var_dump($latest);
```

The var_dump will show you $latest also changed. This is because actually $test[0] is only a reference to the instance of the StdClass, and that instance is copied to $latest. When the instance changes, both references to the instance will show you the same values, from the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

you are cutting the value of $latest to 50 characters with the truncate function in your code.

To get the full value of $latest use the code below:

```
$announcements = $dbc->query($q)->results(); //Returns array of objects
$announcements = prepareMessage($announcements); //Adds html tags to values
$latest = $announcements[0]; //Assign first index to variable


function prepareMessage($message) {
    foreach($message as $values => $key) {
        $key->title = '<h2>'.$key->title.'</h2>';
        $key->name = '<p>'.$key->name.'</p>';
        $key->date = '<small>'.humanDate($key->date).'</small>';
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Or you can change the amount of characters to display on this line (where "50" are the amount of characters to show and "0" is where to start from)

```
$key->announcement = substr($key->announcement, 0, 50) . '...</p>';
```

Comment: He is applying truncate() to $announcements... now unless $latest is a reference this won't answer his question. :)

Comment: I don't think your answer is really explaining why changing the value on $announcement[0] also changes the value in $latest.

Comment: M. Adam Kendall's answer explains exactly why and how... op didn't mention which php version was using.

Comment: but its not explaining why the value is cut off (changing) as stated in the question?